# Unable to install mysql2

Tags: mysql, compiling, ruby, postgresql

I tried to install `mysql` using below command

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'
```

However I am getting the below error

```
    Fetching: mysql2-0.3.18.gem (100%)
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/jophy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170221-7481-38xom2.rb extconf.rb

extconf.rb failed 
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
```

When I opened `mkmf.log`, I could find the below error:-

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to install the `libmysqlclient-dev` package

Comment: please remove postgresql tag

Answer (score 2):

As [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) mentions in his comment, you need to install the [libmysqlclient-dev package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libmysqlclient-dev+&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) which is available for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu from Precise through Zesty and can be installed Either through the Software Center or from the CLI (terminal) with the command `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Sources:

[Unable to install mysql2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885840/unable-to-install-mysql2/885849#comment1382922_885840)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832120/error-error-installing-mysql2-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: Thanks for your response.

when i tried this comment sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev, it worked.

but when i typed following command bundle exec rake db:migrate, i am getting below error

Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Comment: Have you by anay chance perused the answers in the second source linked in my answer? You might try `gem install mysql2`

Comment: Regardless this new error wasn't in your original question. One question often leads to another, which is fine, but there may be others with this one that didn't have your original question so I recommend opening a new question for this new error: Be that as it may you might find some clues [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753584/how-to-fix-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-ly-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-sta)